# Duplicate function update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a duplicate system, I have a form revision with a recording.

For example, I have to change the value of my field hour_start => 18:00

[image]

I want to replace by the value => 08:00

[image]

When, I validate the form I have an error message:

[image]

The value of my field hour start is always the same

[image]

In fact, my duplicate system must work for dates, but if I change a value of my field hour_start, it must pass...

```
public function update(revisionRequest $request, $id)
    {

        $exists = Revision::where('date_revision_start', $request->get('date_revision_start'))->where('date_revision_end', $request->get('date_revision_end'))->where('hour_start', $request->get('hour_start'))->where('hour_end', $request->get('hour_end'))->where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))->where('fk_garage', $request->get('fk_garage'))->count();

        $date_revision_start = $request->get('date_revision_start');
        $date_revision_end = $request->get('date_revision_end');

        $conflict = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_revision_start)
            ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_revision_start)
            ->first();

        $conflict2 = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_revision_end)->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_revision_end)->first();

        if(isset($conflict2) || isset($conflict)){
            return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
             ->with('error', 'Duplicate date! ');
        }


        else{
            $revisions = Revision::find($id);
            $revisions->date_revision_start = $request->get('date_revision_start');
            $revisions->date_revision_end = $request->get('date_revision_end');
            $revisions->hour_start = $request->get('hour_start');
            $revisions->hour_end = $request->get('hour_end');
            $revisions->fk_garage = $request->get('fk_garage');
            $revisions->fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
            $revisions->save();
            return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
                    ->with('success', 'ok')->withInput();
        }

    }
```

Thank you for your help.

**Edit**:@Watercayman

I test this:

```
if( (isset($conflict2) && $conflict2->id !== $id)
        || (isset($conflict) && $conflict->id !== $id) ){
            return redirect()->route('entretiens.index')
             ->with('error', 'Duplicate date! ');
        }

        @dd($conflict->id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have to check for duplicates on the revision is fine for the `store` method, where you don't want to create a new revision that is on top of another revision's dates for the same motorbike.  However, you have a bit of a logic choice to make now for the `*update*` method.

You could opt to only allow the user to change the time, but not the dates.  This way, there is no chance of moving the revision to fall on top of another existing revision date.  To do so, just remove the fields for date on the form and then remove the duplicate check logic in `update()` (IE remove everything but the model update code).

If, however, you want to allow them to move the date, you need to add some logic in the `update()` method to check to see if the revision you are working on is not the same one that comes back in `$conflict`.  IE - if they move the date of Revision A, the duplicate check is going to come back and say 'duplicate' because it sees itself (Revision A) as being in conflict for dates.

I think you can fix this by adding a check to see if the duplicate date is the same one being updated.  If it is, let it pass, if the change has made the Revision A on top of some other revision, let it fail and send duplicate message.

Again - this is not the most efficient, but hopefully the easiest to understand fix.  Just add a check to see if either of `$conflicts` is the same as the revision that has come into this update.  Something like:

```
if( (isset($conflict2) && $conflict2->id !== intval($id))
    || (isset($conflict) && $conflict->id !== intval($id)) ){  ...  }
```

This assumes that `$id` in the method parameter is the `id` of the **revision** from the form.

Comment: Thanks for the time you have spent responding to me. I used your line of code and I still have the same duplicate problem.If you have a suggestion, do not hesitate...

Comment: Can you please dump the following and let me know what the results are?  `$id`, `$conflict->id`, `$conflict2->id`.   This code should work.  I am wondering if `$id` is null or not the right value for the form revision

Comment: I have tested this => ` @dd($conflict->id);` but nothing happen. I have edited my first post... weird...

Comment: test it above the if() line - the if() line is firing, so you never get to see the dd() :)  Please do dd($id) first - that's the one that has me curious.

Comment: For `dd($id);` I have "3"  then for `dd($conflict->id);` I have an error message Trying to get property 'id' of non-object and for `dd($conflict2->id);` I have "3"

Comment: Oh shoot I wonder if the value from the form is reading as a `string`.  Let me edit my answer with `intval()` - please try with the edited code.  You could also probably get away with `!=` instead of `!==`, but maybe better to be precise ;)

Comment: Bravooooo !! :) It works ... I do not know how to thank you. thank you very much for your time Watercayman, you are the best. :)

Comment: excuse me for disturbing you, can you help me here please?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779665/duplicate-system-on-two-forms/57782393#57782393

I am really stuck