# Duplicate system on two forms

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My project is to create a small  driving school for motorbike.

I have 4 tables: `Former, Training, Revision, Motorbike`

[image]

My functions create() and store() work for my 4 forms.

However, I have a big problem ... If, my motorbike is in `revision` on`03/09/2019` to `05/09/2019` for the motorbike`000001`

and that I encode in my form `training` a booking on `03/09/2019` with as motorbike number`000001`; Normally the motorbike is unavailable, how can I handle that?

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to create a duplicate system for the forms `revision` ->`training` or the inverse  `training` ->`revision`

In my Controller Revision I have this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $revisions = Revision::oldest()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.revisions.index', compact('revisions'))
          ->with('i', (request()->input('page',1) -1)*5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()            
    {

        $motorbikes = Motorbike::all();
        return view('admin.revisions.create', compact('motorbikes','revisions'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $date_revision_start = $request->get('date_revision_start');
        $date_revision_end = $request->get('date_revision_end');
        $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start');
        $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end');
        $garage = $request->get('garage');
        $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');

        $conflict = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_revision_start)
            ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_revision_start)
            ->first();

        $conflict2 = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_revision_end)->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_revision_end)->first();



        if(isset($conflict2) || isset($conflict)){
            return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
             ->with('error', 'duplicate');
        }

       else{
        Revision::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }

    }
```

And for the Controller Training

```
public function index()
    {
        $trainings = Training::oldest()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.trainings.index', compact('trainings'));
                with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) -1) *5);
    }



    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {   
        $motorbikes = Motorbike::all();
        $formers = Former::all();
        return view('admin.trainings.create', compact('motorbikes','formers','trainings'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'date_seance' => 'required',
                'hour_start' => 'required',
                'hour_end' => 'required',
                'fk_motorbike' => 'required',
                'fk_former' => 'required'


        ]);


       $exists = Training::where('date_seance', $request->get('date_seance'))->where('hour_start', $request->get('hour_start'))->where('hour_end', $request->get('hour_end'))->where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))->count();

       if (!$exists){
            Training::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                ->with('success', 'Add');
        }

        else{
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                ->with('error', 'Duplicate ');

        } 


    }
```

Could you help me please, because I'm still a beginner in Laravel and I want to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

```
 $date_start = $request->get('date_seance'); 
       $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');

       $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start');
       $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end');

        $conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
            ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_start)
            ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_start)
            ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $hour_start)
            ->where('hour_end', "<=" , $hour_end)
            ->first();

        $conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
            ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)
            ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $hour_start)
            ->where('hour_end', "<=" , $hour_end)
            ->first();

        if(isset($conflictTraining) || isset($conflictRevision)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                 ->with('error', 'Duplicate ');
        }

        else{
            Training::create($request->all());
                return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Add');
    }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you elaborate more about your problem?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to validate that the chosen motorbike is available (i.e not in revision) when a training booking form is submitted - is that right?

Comment: @James: Yes that's right ... I'm stuck for several days ... :-(

Comment: @Jesus Erwin Suarez: when my motorbike (number) `000001` is under revision on` 08/09/2019` to `09/09/2019` and then I have to organize a seance on ` 08/09 / 2019` always with the motobike  `000001`, I must to have a checking system that checks whether the motorbike is available or not ... Here, for example, the bike must be unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, and you have almost got what you need already.  You can model the *training duplicate* code after the duplicate revision code and add a very similar revision duplicate code to get your answer.

I am going to explain in detail and repeat myself codewise, but hopefully this will be easier to understand.  You can compress this code once it makes sense to you.  Not the least of which would be to make the duplicate code for revision a separate method within your **Controller Revision**, so that both **Controller Revision** and **Controller Training** can draw from it.  But that's later - for now let's get it working.

On your **Controller Training**, remove the `$exists` stuff for now.  First we need to make sure there is no **revision** at the same time as the user wants to apply **training** for the motorbike.  In this case, though, there is only one date for Training in your model, so only one `$conflict` check for the revision:

```
$date_start = $request->get('date_seance'); // I assume your form field for training is date_seance
$fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');

// NOTE: the $date_start MAY need to be converted to a Carbon instance if it doesn't work - same as before

$conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_start)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_start)
        ->first();
```

Now we need to check to see if there is a conflict for **training**.  We can use the same PHP variables already assigned, just change the model we are querying.  I assume seance is ONE day per your model:

```
$conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)
        ->first();
```

And then it is a very similar if-check to the one we used in the revision check:

```
if(isset($conflictTraining) || isset($conflictRevision)){
     return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'Duplicate ');
else{
     Training::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('success', 'Add');
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Watercayman, I do not know how to thank you ... It works, I am infinitely grateful to you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is making use of a [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes) in the Training model. I'll assume that a motorbike is the whole day unavailable when in revision.

```
public function scopeAvailable($query) 
{
    return $query->whereNotBetween('trainings.date_sceance', [
        'revisions.date_revision_start' => function($q) {
             return $q->where('trainings.fk_motorbike', '=', 'revisions.fk_motorbike');
        },
        'revisions.date_revision_end' => function($q) {
             return $q->where('trainings.fk_motorbike', '=', 'revisions.fk_motorbike');
        }]
    );
}
```

I haven't test this code. It is possible it won't give what you expect, in other words, my proposition is wrong. Using the scope would be

```
$exists = Training::where('date_seance', $request->get('date_seance'))->available()->count();
```