# Adapt my function store() in update() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The function store() is

```
       $date_start = $request->get('date_seance'); 
       $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');

       $conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
            ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_start)
            ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_start)
            ->first();

        $conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
            ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)
            ->first();

        if(isset($conflictTraining) || isset($conflictRevision)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                 ->with('error', 'Duplicate ');
        }

        else{
            Training::create($request->all());
                return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Add');
    }
```

I want to adapt my function `store()`for the method `update()`, because I want to modify my different values of my fields.

I know to change the value of the date_seance but the function update() doesn't change the others values ex: `hour_start, hour_end, fk_motorbike, fk_former`, it's a problem...

```
public function update(trainingsRequest $request, $id)
    {   
        $date_seance = $request->get('date_seance'); 
        $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start');
        $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end');
        $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
        $fk_former = $request->get('fk_former');


        $conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
            ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_seance)
            ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_seance)
            ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $date_seance)
            ->where('hour_end', "<=" , $date_seance)
            ->first();

        $conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
            ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_seance)
            ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $date_seance)
            ->where('hour_end', "<=" , $date_seance)
            ->first();


        if(isset($conflictTraining) || isset($conflictRevision)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                 ->with('error', 'Duplicate ');
        }


        else{
            $trainings = Training::find($id);
            $trainings->date_seance = $request->get('date_seance');
            $trainings->hour_start = $request->get('hour_start');
            $trainings->hour_end = $request->get('hour_end');
            $trainings->fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
            $trainings->fk_former = $request->get('fk_former');
            $trainings->save();
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('success', 'update')->withInput();
        }
    }
```

I know the problem is here:

```
 if(isset($conflictTraining) || isset($conflictRevision)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                 ->with('error', 'Duplicate ');
        }
```

I have tried this but without success:

```
 if( (isset($conflictTraining) && $conflictTraining->id !== intval($id))
        || (isset($conflictRevision) && $conflictRevision->id !== intval($id)) ){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
             ->with('error', 'Duplicate date! ');
        }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are looking to update a **Training**, you don't want to check to see if the incoming form `id` is the same for the **Revision** in the if-check.  The `id` that is coming in (that you are comparing to) is for a Training.  So the if-check should look more like this:

```
if( (isset($conflictTraining) && $conflictTraining->id !== intval($id))
    || isset($conflictRevision)) ){
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
         ->with('error', 'Duplicate date! ');
    }
```

Leaving out the `id` check from the **Revision** above will not make a false hit (`id` of **Revision** will likely never === the incoming `id` of the **Training**, and if it does, it is wrong since it is comparing the wrong `id`)

The conflict check for Revision, however, may also be causing you problems.  This line:

```
 $conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_seance)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_seance)
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $date_seance)  // <--Suggest remove this
        ->where('hour_end', "<=" , $date_seance)  // <--Suggest remove 
        ->first();
```

is checking against an hour start of the **Revision** model.  If there is no `hour_start/end` in that model, OR if you are just checking to see if the `seance` is the same day as the **Revision**, this might cause problems.  I would remove the query to check against `hour_start` and `hour_end`.

Same thing *might* apply to the **Training** query.  If you want to get granular to the point of checking if the new training from the form is at the same hour, this is fine.  But if so, this is a much more detailed check - IE does the new training start at the same time, or finish at the same time.  This will not, however, check to see if the training hits in the middle of the old training the way you have it set up (both check for `<=`).  You may wish to consider just checking if the new training is on same day as old training and any potential revision.  IE remove the where checks on time for the training query to make this simpler - once you get it working, maybe add in more strict query parameters like the hour of start / finish.

IE I suggest removing this for now till you get it working:

```
->where('hour_start', "<=" , $date_seance)
->where('hour_end', "<=" , $date_seance)
```

Comment: Thank you Watercayman my problem of modification is solve. regarding my hour_start and hour_end problem, do I open a new post or edit my first post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779665/duplicate-system-on-two-forms/57791909#57791909

Comment: My pleasure.  I would open a new question.  But I would think through your workflow / logic before you create the question.  It is important to decide what your goal is with the time thing.  If it is the same bike, the same day, is it not enough to know that the bike is unavailable for the whole day for the revision?  Then, next question for you - is it enough to know the bike is in training for the day, or do you need to get granular enough to know that it is in training in the morning, but must know if it is available in the afternoon.  If so, you need the query on the Training.

Comment: For example, the motorbike is reserved for a training on 6/09/2019, 8:00 to 10:00 (number of the motorbike 000001 & former "Alain") ... Then, the motorbike (000001) is reserved always on 06/09/2019 (12:00 to 14:00 & former "Alain" ).

On 07/09/2019, revision the morning 08:00 to 12:00 motorbike 000001, then another training 16:00 to 18:00 still with the number of the motorbike 000001.

I  do not know if my explanations are accurate now?

Comment: Yes, I understand.  So, looks like you DO NOT need the hour on the **Revision** but, that you want to check against the hour start and finish on the **Training**.   Try with your original query for `$conflictTraining`, but change the operator in the LAST where to `>=`, so `->where('hour_end', ">=" , $date_seance).  Give it s a shot.  Hard to do this in comments, but that might work.

Comment: thank you for your help, I will open a new topic, if it does not work. You can take a look when you have time.

Comment: I created a new post, I still have 3 problems ... When you have time, you can help me please, here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57796420/booking-and-management

Comment: Sure I'll take a look