# Booking and Management

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am still a beginner in laravel...

The motorbike is reserved for a training on `6/09/2019`, from `8:00` to `10:00` (number of the motorbike `000001` & former `Alain`).

[image]

Then, the motorbike `000001` is reserved always on `06/09/2019`, from `12:00` to `14:00` for the former `Alain`.

I have an error message => `duplicate` // **(first problem)**

[image]

On `07/09/2019`, `revision` the morning, from `08:00` to `12:00` with the motorbike `000001`

[image]

If, I want to book on `07/09/2019` a `training`, from `08:00` to `12:00` with the motorbike `000001`. It blocks (duplicate) OK , Well !

However, I enter always on `07/09/2019` a `training`, from `16:00` to `18:00` with the motorbike `000001`. It blocks (duplicate) also, it's a problem **(second problem)**

Yet a problem, how to manage the management of trainers ???

I can not have 2 times the same instructors who teach a conduct at the same time ... **(third problem)**.

**Edit 05/09/2019**

My code for now

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'date_seance' => 'required',
                'hour_start' => 'required',
                'hour_end' => 'required',
                'fk_motorbike' => 'required',
                'fk_former' => 'required'


        ]);


       $date_start = $request->get('date_seance'); 
       $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start'); 
       $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end'); 
       $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
       $fk_former = $request->get('fk_former');


        $conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)  // Bike is conflicted?
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  // Same day?
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  // Within same time slot?
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->where('fk_former', $request->get('fk_former')) // Same trainer as requested?
        ->where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike')) 
        ->first();  

        $conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_start)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_start)
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->first();  

        if(isset($conflictTraining) || isset($conflictRevision)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                 ->with('error', 'Duplicate ');
        }

        else{
            Training::create($request->all());
                return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Add');
    }



    }
```

**I still have to check the name of the trainer  via  the motorbike number.**

[image]
I added the model Former, I added the model Former, but I don't understand how I can do checkings ?

**I have 2 problems:**

1)the former can not have 2 seances the same hour with two different motorbikes

2)the motorbike can not have 2  seances  the same hours

I am trying to check the Former:

However, I have an error message: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'fk_former' inconnu dans where clause`

```
$conflictFormer = Former::where('fk_former', $fk_former)  
        ->where('name',  $request->get('name')) 
        ->first();  


        if(isset($conflictTraining) || isset($conflictRevision) || isset($conflictFormer) ){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                 ->with('error', 'Duplicate ');
        }
```

Thank you in advance, for your help and your explanations.

Comment: @Ken, I thought the same thing until I re-read the question.  It's not worded well, as English is clearly his/her second language, but what he's looking for is a solution to a single problem, 'how do I determine if this thing is conflicted within my xxx method'.  I wouldn't have taken the time to answer if it didn't seem like a reasonable question that I might have had when sorting through a bit of a mess of logic.

Comment: @Watercayman: Thanks. Comment and CV removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use similar logic to check for duplicates for Training, Trainer, and Revision.

**Training**

Because training is on one day, you can see if there is a training on the same day, and within the same time frame as that requested by the user from the form.  You can also, in the same query, check if the requested trainer is in that training, and if that particular motorbike is the one scheduled for the training:

```
 $conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)  // Bike is conflicted?
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_seance)  // Same day?
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  // Within same time slot?
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->where('fk_former', $request->get('fk_former')) // Same trainer as requested?
        ->first();
```

**Revision**

This gets a little more complex because there are potentially multiple days.  If you want to know if a bike is in revision at any time during the day requested by the form `seance`, your code above will work fine.  However, if you want to look to see if maybe the bike can be in training in the afternoon when it is only in revision in the morning, that is different.

Because we are looking for a specific time on a specific day which may be at the beginning, middle, or end of that span of days for the revision, I think it would be easiest to explain by making this a bit big - you can refactor and tighten later if this works.  First, I would grab the revision that conflicts with the day the same way as in your code:

```
$conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_start)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_start)
        ->first();
```

Now that you have the revision which matches your user's day, you can then look to see if the specific hours requested by the user for training are in this revision.  The hard part, and the point which you need to decide in your workflow logic is that do you assume that if it is in revision for a few hours, that it will *always* be just one day in revision?  If so, you can augment the query above with similar clauses as your training:

```
$conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_start)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_start)
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->first();
```

If the user can enter a revision 'lazily' where it might be for 8:00-11:00, but you *allow multiple days*, this won't work every time, and doesn't make sense from a logic point of view (if you enter 8:00-11:00 for Jan 24-Jan 30, which day is it in the garage?).  I'm not sure you can reliably code this check for it if you allow for multiple days AND only for a few hours.  There is no easy way to check if the hours are on the specific day of `seance` if there are multiple days in between start & end.

If possible, when a revision is hourly, it would probably make life easier to limit the user to one day for the revision.

Comment: Hello Watercayman, thank you very much for your help and the time you spent on your explanations.

I'm trying to understand how I can check the names of trainers and motorbikes?

I edited my first message.

Comment: You were so close!!  You had the right idea in mind to create a `$conflictFormer`.  You just need to check against the right model - not **Former**, since that doesn't have the training attached.  Think about doing it this way:  For the conflict of trainers - use the same **query** as `$conflictTraining`, but remove the `fk_motorbike` line, and replace with `fk_former`.  This will give list of formers who conflict.  Motorbike should not conflict with trainings, that is already checked via the `$conflictTraining` query, I think

Comment: Also, consider narrowing your questions down to *one* problem.  A moderator set a Close Vote on your question last night, stating that you should make your questions about a single thing, rather than multiple problems.  I explained that you were looking for just one thing, but I think you may run into problems in future with questions that are asking about many 'problems'.  I understand that they are all related, but take note of how you are asking for best possible question / answer.  Consider focusing on one issue per question to tighten what you are asking when possible :)

Comment: Thank you, my problem is solve for the cas `former`, Thank you a lot for your help. Sorry for the questions on this post...  I will open other post no problem

Comment: My pleasure!  And no worries about the questions, I knew what you were trying to do :)